# Zoho with NodeMailer not working error code: 'EDNS'

Tags: javascript, nodemailer, zoho

I try to send an email with Nodemailer and always get the same error:

```
    hostname: 'smtp.zoho.com',
    secure: true,
    port: 465,
    auth: {
        user: 'maria@mydomain.my',
        pass: 'apppassgenerated'
    }
});
```

I tried too:

```
   service: 'Zoho',
    auth: {
        user: 'maria@mydomain.my',
        pass: 'apppassgenerated'
    }
});
```

I always get: { Error: queryA EREFUSED smtp.zoho.com
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:213:19)
  errno: 'EREFUSED',
  code: 'EDNS',
  syscall: 'queryA',
  hostname: 'smtp.zoho.com',
  command: 'CONN' }

Answer (score 2):

Ok, It was because I was using free plan of Google Functions. If you want to integrate external tools you have to pay ‍♂️

Comment: I had the exact same problem, thanks for sharing your answer!